# Is it possible to directly access a text file in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I build a web application with using game API + Laravel. To be verified my app, I have to put a specified text file to be accessed directly on the application, such as [my site's URL]/xxx.txt.

However, I couldn't do it. I created a PHP file which include the file For example, include 'xxx.txt'. But it wasn't permitted.

Comment: Just upload the text file onto the server?? Whats php got  to do with it?

Comment: Assuming that you have Laravel set up correctly... just put the file in the `public/` folder.

Comment: My question was solved. Thank you. Come to think of it, I successed applying css files in public folder. I think I had a bias that I couldn't access directly text files in public folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:**

1st create a file

for example: *superman.txt*

**Step 2:**

put that file in a directory

for example: site url's directory "http://www.example.net/superman.txt"

**Step 3:**

then create a controller which loads the file:

**Step 4:**

then You can use file_get_content() to fetch data from that file from controller

**step 5:**

use route::get() to determine a url for that file

Here you go . Now you can Access your file from a url :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I try it.

Comment: If the answer is ok .. can you please select this as a correct answer ? :-)

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't finish writing this code because of sudden happenings. I will select this as the right answer after finishing it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I seem that it isn't correct. 

First, it didn't work when I put a text file to view folder and create a controller. Next, it worked after moving the file to public folder. Last, it also worked when putting text file which isn't related to any controller.

That is, it works as long as putting text file to public folder.